# setuptools 'entry_points' parameter usage

Tags: python, setuptools

Looking through some python code, ive found an argument `entry_points` to the setuptools.setup function. I cant see this argument in any of the API docs for setuptools / distutils. Can anyone clarify what format this parameter should take, or even better, where its defined in the API docs?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the documentation for Distribute, it's a lot better. The section you want to look at is [Dynamic Discovery of Services and Plugins](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dynamic-discovery-of-services-and-plugins):

> The entry_points argument to setup() accepts either a string with .ini-style sections, or a dictionary mapping entry point group names to either strings or lists of strings containing entry point specifiers. An entry point specifier consists of a name and value, separated by an = sign. The value consists of a dotted module name, optionally followed by a : and a dotted identifier naming an object within the module.

Another good explanation can be found on the  [Hitchhiker’s Guide to Packaging](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/); there is a section [dedicated to the entry_points feature](http://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creation.html#entry-points):

> Entry points are a Setuptools/Distribute feature that’s really handy in one specific case: register something under a specific key in package A that package B can query for.